# 2-D character array

Tags: c, output

```
#include<stdio.h>

void main()
{
    char a[10][5] = {"hi", "hello", "fellow"};
    printf("%s",a[0]);
}
```

*Why this code printing only* **hi**

```
#include<stdio.h>

void main()
{
    char a[10][5] = {"hi", "hello", "fellow"};
    printf("%s",a[1]);
}
```

*While this code is printing "**hellofellow**"*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why this code printing only hi

You've told `printf` to print the string stored at `a[0]`, and that string happens to be `"hi"`.

> While this code is printing "hellofellow"

This one is by coincidence, in fact your code ought to be rejected by the compiler due to [a constraint violation](http://www.iso-9899.info/n1570.html#6.7.9p2):

> No initializer shall attempt to provide a value for an object not contained within the entity being initialized.

The string `"fellow"`, specifically the `'w'` at the end of it does not fit within the `char[5]` being initialised, and this violates the C standard. Perhaps also by coincidence, your compiler provides an extension (making it technically a non-C compiler), and so you don't see [the error messages](http://ideone.com/5KQTwC) that I do:

```
prog.c:3:6: error: return type of 'main' is not 'int' [-Werror=main]
 void main()
      ^
prog.c: In function 'main':
prog.c:5:37: error: initializer-string for array of chars is too long [-Werror]
     char a[10][5] = {"hi", "hello", "fellow"};
                                     ^
```

Note that the second error message is complaining about `"fellow"`, but not `"hello"`. Your `"hello"` initialisation [is valid by exception](http://www.iso-9899.info/n1570.html#6.7.9p14):

> An array of character type may be initialized by a character string literal or UTF-8 string literal, optionally enclosed in braces. Successive bytes of the string literal (**including the terminating null character if there is room** or if the array is of unknown size) initialize the elements of the array.

The emphasis is mine. What the emphasised section states is that if there isn't enough room for a terminal `'\0'` character, that won't be used in the initialisation.

Answer (score 2):

Your code:

```
 char a[10][5] = {"hi", "hello", "fellow"};
```

Allocates 10 `char [5]`

"hello" takes up 5 so there is no room for the terminating `\0`, so it runs into "fellow"

If you try it, `a [3]` should be "w" because "fellow" is too big and the "w" runs over from `a[2]` to `a[3]`

Aside from being undefined behavior, it is confusing what you were trying to do

Answer (score 2):

It will give *undefines behaviour* as `string` are `null-terminated`.

And element `hello` has length of `5`.
Declare your array as `a[10][7]` then you will get intended output.

See here -https://ideone.com/c2zUs0

> Why this code printing only hi

Because  `a[0][2]` is `null` indicating termination thus giving you `hi`.

Answer (score 1):

This is **undefined behavior** due to insufficient space to store `\0` character.

Please note that the memory allocated is `5`bytes per string in your array of strings. Thus, for the `a[1]` there is not sufficient memory to store the `\0` character as all five bytes are assigned with `"hello"`.

> Thus, the subsequent memory is read until the `\0` character is found.

Thus, you can change the line:

```
char a[10][5] = {"hi", "hello", "fellow"};
```

to

```
char a[][7] = {"hi", "hello", "fellow"};
```

> Why this code printing only **hi**

This is because the `\0` character is already encountered at `a[0][2]` and thus the reading of the characters is stopped.

Comment: ["Successive bytes of the string literal (including the terminating null character **if there is room** or if the array is of unknown size) initialize the elements of the array."](http://www.iso-9899.info/n1570.html#6.7.9p14), emphasis is mine... It's not the `'\0'` that causes UB.

Answer (score 1):

**What Your Code Does:**

Look at the following statement:

```
char a[10][5] = {"hi", "hello", "fellow"};
```

It allocates `10` rows. `5` characters are allocated for each index of `a`.

**What is the Problem:**

Strings are [Null Terminated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null-terminated_string) there is always a `null-terminator` needed to be stored except for the given characters, so basically the used size of array is `numOfCharacters+1`, the extra one byte is for the null terminator. When you are initializing the array with exactly `size` number of characters, the `null terminator` is skipped. Normally the character array value is printed until the first `\0`(null terminator) is not found. Please also have a look at [this](http://facultyfp.salisbury.edu/despickler/personal/Resources/AdvancedDataStructures/Handouts/C_StyleStrings.pdf).

**The Solution:**

No need to worry about this problem, all you need to do is just to set the size equal to the `numOfCharactersInString + 1`. You can use the following statement:

```
char a[10][7] = {"hi", "hello", "fellow"};
```

Since the largest string is `"fellow"` which contains `6` characters, you need to set the size `6 + 1` that is why the statement should use `char a[10][7]` instead of char `a[10][5]`

Hope it helps.